# How to import external folder into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I'm new to android studio IDE. i have a problem importing the Parse folder(module) in to studio. I know how to import jar files in to studio. if my question is not clear please ask me for further details. thanks in advance.
I tried importing(File → Import Module…) but there is no finish button, pleasse see the screen shot[image]

Comment: What is "the Pares folder"?

Comment: @Alex Lockwood .Parse.com has given this https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android to download. from that i should import ParseLoginUI.

Answer (score 0):

> File → Import Module…

Comment: What version of Android Studio do you have installed?

Comment: Android studio beta 0.8.9

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest canary build (I believe v0.8.12)?